# Python Regex To VB.net

Tags: python, vb.net, regex

I made a program in Python and now I whant to transfert it to vb.net. But I have some difficulties with the vb.net regular expression.... Someone can help me please?

There are my Python regex:

```
id = re.search('(?<=watch\?v\=)[\w|-]+|(?<=/v/)[\w|-]+', src)
id = id.group(0)

t = re.search('(?<=\&t\=)[\w|-]+', src)
t = t.group()
```

It's supposed to fin the value of ?v=Value&SomeOtherContent and &t=Value&SomeOtherContent

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to parse query strings is by using a `NameValueCollection`, using the [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method. This also takes care of encoding.

For example:

```
NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("?var1=1&var2=2");
```

Comment: Oh, good to know ^^ But the thing it's that the &t= is not in a URL but in a string in the page source.